# Programming for Linux on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, embedded, real-time

I am in a strange scenario, where I must use a work windows 8 desktop how ever I am writing code to be run on a real time Linux machine. I am writing code for a Real-time system, so will need to implement many non-windows headers like RTAI and such. Obviously I can not run these on windows 8, so was curious if anyone had any suggestions for compiling and testing without having to upload code to the RTOS based computer I am programming for each time I want to run a program. I unfortunately can't use a virtual machine and would like to avoid coding in the terminal in order to remotely code on the linux machine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you required to use a Windows 8 desktop for this?  There are tools that advertise being able to work on Linux targeted code in Visual Studio, but I haven't used them.  Search for WinGDB and/or VisualGDB if you're game.  I have no idea how those tools deal with the occasional source tree that depends on filenames being case sensitive.

Comment: How much of the real-time specific code are you invoking in your program?  When you say "testing" in this context, then I would have to assume it's none.  If you just want to _pretend_ the stuff is there, you could obtain a directory listing of the relevant files and just touch empty versions into some fallback include path location on your development machine.  If you actually need the stuff in those headers, then you would have to do something fancier like stubbing all the specific functions to do nothing and provide sensible return values.  Personally, I prefer to code in the terminal.

Comment: Separate question is why do you want to avoid uploading and compiling the code on the remote machine?

Comment: It is a shame that you did not explain why you could not use a VM since that is the simplest solution - your reasons for not doing so may be spurious.  Cygwin may be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can *code* in Windows or whatever OS you like, what system your programming computer uses has absolutely nothing to do with the target system.

The cross compiler you are using must obviously be for the intended target system. Same goes for debugger & program download tools. Your program must either run in a simulator or it must run on the real target. The latter is strongly recommended.

So all you have to do is to acquire the right software tools. Since these are almost always written for Windows, that should be easy.

Comment: For my current project, I am compiling for ARM using a cross-compiler that runs on Windows, which I running in a VirtualBox on my Mac laptop.   Anything's possible...